# Components are replacements of directives? or component is a special type of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

Components are looks like same as directive without DOM manipulation. Without DOM manipulation means then why we go to use Components?

So My Question is : **(Components are replacements of directives? or component is a special type of directive?) and why?**

kindly let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: It's pretty clear here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: _"without DOM manipulation"_ Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 1.5 introduced the .component() helper method, which is much simpler than the .directive() definition and encourages best practices (e.g. thinking about an application as bunch of components, take a look at ReactJS, web components) and common default behaviours.

If you are writing Angular 1.5.x application, using .component() will allow you to write in an Angular 2 style as well, which will in turn should make upgrading to Angular 2 less stressful.